# who can change pdfmake header size image is too small?

Tags: javascript, header, pdfmake

I want to make the header part of the pdf file as in the figure, but the logo image is too small. When you want to increase its width, the picture disappears. can you help me.

http://live.datatables.net/jatobaqi/227/edit  there is my code

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q9bfb.png)  there is result

```
$(document).ready( function () {
       var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    dom: 'Bfrtip',
    buttons: [

        {
            extend: 'pdfHtml5',
           className: 'pdf-buton',
            customize: function ( doc ) {
              
             var now = new Date(); 
             var jsDate = now.getDate()+'/'+(now.getMonth()+1)+'/'+now.getFullYear();
              
              doc['header']=(function() {
                    return {
                      columns: [
                        {
                          alignment: 'left',
                          italics: false,
                          bold: true,
                          text: ['RAPOR'],
                          fontSize: 25,
                          margin: [27,0,0,0]
                        },
                        {
                          image: 'image'
                          width: 30
                          
                        }
                      ],
                      margin: 10
                    };
                  });
              
              doc['footer']=(function(page,pages) {
                    return {
                      columns: [
                        {
                          alignment: 'left',
                          text: ['www.---------.com']
                        },

                        {
                          alignment: 'right',
                          text: ['Sayfa ', { text: page.toString() }, ' / ',  { text: pages.toString() }]
                        }
                      ],
                      margin: 20
                    };
                  });
              
              doc.content.splice( 0, 1, {
                    margin: [ 0, 0, 0, 5 ],
                    alignment: 'left',
                  text:  'Firma/Şahıs:' + ' firma ',
                  fontSize: 12,
                },{
                    margin: [ 0, 0, 0, 5 ],
                    alignment: 'left',
                  text:  ['Tarih: ', { text: jsDate.toString() }],
                  fontSize: 12,
                },
                                  );
                console.log(doc.content)
            }
        },
    ]
```

});
} );

Answer (score 0):

You have to adjust marigns. It will work like that:

```
          doc['header']=(function() {
                    return {
                      columns: [
                        {
                          alignment: 'left',
                          italics: false,
                          bold: true,
                          text: ['RAPOR'],
                          fontSize: 25,
                          marginTop: 10,
                          marginLeft: 30,
                          width:500

                        },
                        {
                          image: 'data:image/png;base64,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',
                          width: 62,
                          marginTop: 2,
                          
                        }
                      ],

                    };
                  });
```